# JQuery - Servlet post fails erratically

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

I am new to JQuery, I am running into a wierd issue here, I try to do a post of my HTML form to a servlet, and try to print data on the servlet. Data gets printed most of the times I submit the form (say 7 times out of 10) with new values. But It fails the other 3 times, I could not find a pattern at which this is failing.

I tried using firebug and chrome tool, I don't see an error on the console, and I get 200 response in the resources/HTML tool in chrome every time I submit the form with correct values set.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>   

<form id="fcall">
    <p> Start Date:  <input  type="text" name="start" id="ibox_start"> 
        End Date: <input type="text" name="end" id="ibox_end"> </p>
        <div id="buttonID"> 
     <input type="submit" value=" Find " class="button"></div>

</form>
```

main.js

```
$().ready(

    function(){
        $('#ibox_start').datepicker();
        $('#ibox_end').datepicker();

        $('#fcall').submit(

         function(){

           var start =  $('#ibox_start').val();
           var end = $('#ibox_end').val();
           alert(start);

           $.post("DServlet", {start:start,end:end}, function(data) {});

          }
        );
      }         
    );
```

Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws      ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    String start = request.getParameter("start");
    String end = request.getParameter("end");
    System.out.println("Date Recieved "+start);

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"?  What do you normally see when it works?

Comment: I see the date printed on my eclipse console as "Date Received + 3/3/2013, and sometimes I do not see any date printed when I submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect to see one of the following :

- natural HTML form submission
- natural HTML form submission with a submit handler which validates form values and returns either `true` to allow form submission or `false` to suppress it.
- a submit handler that submits form data by AJAX, establishes a `.done()` handler to handle the HTTP response, and returns `false` to inhibit natural HTML form submission.

The code above looks like a hybrid of these possibilities.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply, The js part of the code which says alert('start') gives me the right popup alert everytime I submit the form, so the form values are populated correctly, I even see the values in firebug. Since I am new to JQuery, so I googled a found out that the way to do a "post" to the servlet.

Comment: Try `return false;` at the bottom of the submit handler. That should give consistent behaviour. Maybe not not what you ultimately want, but consistent.

Comment: Hard to say but I expect you want that `return false;` plus some code in the `$.post()` callback function. Try `alert(data);` to get you started, then migrate to something more adventurous like `$("#message").text(data);` to display the returned string in a div or span with `id="message"` hard-coded somewhere on the page.